# How to get userIdentity from inside javascript adapter?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am on MobileFirst 7.1, and I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243330/how-to-get-user-id-from-adapter): Get user id from inside a protected adapter but this time is in javascript.

I have followed the [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/invoking-adapter-procedures-hybrid-client-applications/) and the protected procedure triggers login, I have made sure that application-descriptor.xml contains `<userIdentityRealms>MyRealm</userIdentityRealms>` however user identity is null(again).

How can I get the user identity from inside the following procedure?

```
function myProcedure() {
    // I want to get the userid this Java into Javascript, 
    // SecurityAPI security = serverAPI.getSecurityAPI();
    // OAuthUserIdentity identity = security.getSecurityContext().getUserIdentity();
    // String userid = identity.getId();
    var userid = ???
    var facade = new com.ibm.jp.facade.SomeFacade();
    var list = facade.SomeMethod(userid);
    return JSON.parse(list);
}
```

In the beginning I was trying to get the user identity from inside the Java facade but it is null. I suspect it is not in the same context? That is why I am trying to get it from the js adapter and pass it as a parameter of `someMethod()`. If there is a better way to get it I would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

```
var user = WL.Server.getActiveUser();
var userid = user.userId;
...
```